# How to print the actual executed mongodb query in type script

Tags: typescript, mongodb

I have searched it but I could not find any solution for that, I am a beginner in typescript it will be huge help guys if anyone could provide the answer.

Comment: Are you looking for `EJSON.stringify(...)`?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit you mean `JSON.stringify()` ?

Comment: `JSON` supports only strings, numbers, true, false, null. `ejson` is an extension of JSON to support more types. It supports all JSON-safe types as well as `Date`, `Binary` and User defined types

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the way `mongoose.set('debug', true);` this does the trick.